# How to make a Frame-like component modal to JInternalFrame and block only that JInernalFrame

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog, jinternalframe

To make it short - my application's main JFrame has 2 JInternalFrames. In one of them, I want to have a JButton which will open a JDialog (/JOptionPane/JInternalFram). I want to set the JDialog modal to that JInternalFrame - I want to block that JInternalFrame and leave the other one accessible. I couldn't achieve this using JDialog as it only accepts Frame, Window and Dialog as owners (and it's not possible to cast from JInternalFrame to Frame). I tried using JOptionPane which accepts JComponent as a parent, but unfortunately it blocks the whole main JFrame. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: @MarkS. The OP *did* post what he had tried and why it didn't work, see hist post: "I couldn't achieve this using JDialog as it only accepts Frame, Window and Dialog as owners (and it's not possible to cast from JInternalFrame to Frame). I tried using JOptionPane which accepts JComponent as a parent, but unfortunately it blocks the whole main JFrame"

Comment: See the [`JOptionPane` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#method.summary) that start with **`showInternal..`**