# How to implement modality to cover a portion of the underlying frame

Tags: java

I see that this is where the regular paradigm breaks - when one wishes to bring up a modal that only blocks a portion of a JFrame.
[an attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520920/how-to-make-a-frame-like-component-modal-to-jinternalframe-and-block-only-that-j)
Consider this example - something like a desktop.  A content pane with an "app window area" and an "app button bar" running along one side of it.  The trick is for a dialog to pop up and block the app window area, but not the button bar.

If I were to implement modality for a modeless dialog, what would I have to do to catch mouse activity over a given Dimension of the underlying contentpane (parent to the dialog in question?), so that I am blocking the user from accessing it?

The only other consideration I can think of is hiding dialogs that have popped up for one "app window" but not for another. I will have to make sure to hide dialogs when switching app windows.

Or anything else special one would have to consider?  I know, the way a modal dialog flashes when clicking a blocked window is a nice effect to have, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have produced a result I think I can work with.  The title bar situation is interesting, but I imagine can be hooked as well, but I hope to have a window with no title bar in the end.

I have a class "AppFrame" subclassing JFrame, and in these snippets below, (which is just test code), I used the AppFrame object as the listener for all things created and listened to.

When the dialog was up, a class boolean "isDialogued" was set to true (shut off on its WindowClosed event, and closed as its manner of ending).

I caught the following events, and checked to see if a dialog was on top of their window, to redirect focus to the dialog at the time.
Mouse press and mouse click to the app panel, 
ActionEvent to (the) button on the app panel 
(all clickable controls need this hook), 
the WindowActivated and WindowClosed events.

"appPanels[]" is an array of panels fed into a CardLayout, each one for its own "app window".  Then, there is an "appBarPanel" panel positioned at right (EAST on the JFrame's contentPane BorderLayout).  appPanels[0] is the panel with the button ("popupButton") on it, which launches a modeless JDialog, referenced in-class as "dialog".

The dialog goes away when switching cards via the 5 buttons (actionPerformed) on the app bar.  Its kind of cool when the dialog is outside the app window area and still hides and shows by clicking on the app bar buttons.  The app window area appears to be effectively modally blocked.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    System.out.println("Action performed: "+source.getClass().getName());

    // App Bar
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if(source == buttons[i]) {
            // card change
            if(i != cardSelected) {
                // Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                cardLayout.show(cardPanel, Integer.toString(i));
                cardSelected = i;
            }
            if(isDialogued) {
                // There is a dialog box right now (would be over card 0)
                if(i==0) {
                    dialog.setVisible(true);
                    dialog.toFront();
                } else {
                    dialog.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    // currently blocking with a modeless on top
    if(isDialogued) {
        if(source != dialog) // dialog shares this event handler
            dialog.toFront();
        return;
    } else {
        if(source == popupButton) {
            isDialogued = true;
            dialog = new JDialog(this, "Pop-Up Dialog");
            dialog.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
            dialog.setSize(500, 120);
            dialog.setBackground(appBackColor);
            JLabel l = new JLabel("hello from app window 0");
            l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            dialog.getContentPane().add(l); 
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.addWindowListener(this);
            // dialog.setEnabled(true);
            dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
            return;
        }
    }       
}

@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    String s = "windowActivated() ";
    if(isDialogued) {
        s = s + "isDialogued ";
        if(e.getSource() != dialog)
            dialog.toFront();
    }
    System.out.println(s + e.getSource().getClass().getName());
}

@Override
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == dialog)
        isDialogued = false;
}

private void mouseDialogCheck(MouseEvent arg0, String s) {
    if(isDialogued) {
        s = s + "isDialogued ";
        s = s + arg0.getSource();
        // 
        if(arg0.getSource() == appPanels[0])
            dialog.toFront();
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    String s = "mouseClicked() ";
    mouseDialogCheck(arg0, s);
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    String s = "mousePressed() ";
    mouseDialogCheck(arg0, s);
}
```

Comment: Having added a JTextField to the app window, I found I could catch the mouse events to it just like to the app panel, but that did not stop it from catching a selection of text in the text field.  (Although with the dialog up the text field can't be edited).  Another note: The glass pane looks like another, more involved way to approach this. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Showhowaglasspanecanbeusedtoblockmouseandkeyevents.htm

Comment: When launching the dialog, I setFocusable on my TextField to false during the dialog's time up, and removed that issue.  Also, underlying window focus will have to be recorded before dialog and restored after, to be perfect about it.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach: I've tested this.  There appear to be 3 ways to approach this with this solution, which I'll call 3 frames.
1) Full-screen only. (this fits my needs)
2) undecorated or unmovable and unresizable window

3) using code to move 3 frames around when dragging the back one (might be ugly)

How to do: Make 3 JFrames.  They are all undecorated.  The first is the back frame, which gets the full size.  Then, two other JFrames are created on top of that one, covering their share of the space (setting sizes and locations along the way).

We'll call one of those smaller frames the app frame, and the other the app bar frame (which is really just like a tool bar).  When making JDialogs on top of the app frame, so that they do not block the app bar frame, make them with

```
new JDialog(appFrame, "Pop-Up", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

Or they will block all the frames.  Using DOCUMENT_MODAL appears to work for me this way. The only other catch are overlapping dialogs when going to the app bar, but that is only one place to deal with keeping up the front-most window - the app bar, and not all the app windows underneath any dialogs.